# SqlException: Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am trying to pull crypto prices from and api and save it into my database using dotnet core 3.1 (preview) and ef core 3. Gettings the data is no issue, but then 'context.SaveChanges()' throws an 'Arithmetic overflow error' exception:

```
'Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.'
```

I already tried increasing the decimal presicion and scale in my model but I am still doing something wrong an cannot find out what it is.

Model:

```
    public class PoloniexTradingPair
    {

        // this is the poloniex ID!
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int PoloniexTradingPairId { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(30,28)")]
        public Decimal last { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(30,28)")]
        public Decimal lowestAsk { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(30,28)")]
        public Decimal highestBid { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(30,28)")]
        public Decimal percentChange { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(30,28)")]
        public Decimal baseVolume { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(38,20)")]
        public Decimal quoteVolume { get; set; }

        public int isFrozen { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(30,28)")]
        public Decimal high24hr { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(30,28)")]
        public Decimal low24hr { get; set; }


    }
```

Resulting Database Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PoloniexTradingPairs](
    [PoloniexTradingPairId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [last] [decimal](30, 28) NOT NULL,
    [lowestAsk] [decimal](30, 28) NOT NULL,
    [highestBid] [decimal](30, 28) NOT NULL,
    [percentChange] [decimal](30, 28) NOT NULL,
    [baseVolume] [decimal](30, 28) NOT NULL,
    [quoteVolume] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
    [isFrozen] [int] NOT NULL,
    [high24hr] [decimal](30, 28) NOT NULL,
    [low24hr] [decimal](30, 28) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PoloniexTradingPairs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PoloniexTradingPairId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Method:

```
void getPoloniexTradingPairs()
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {


        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {


            var rates = httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker");
            JObject rates_json = JObject.Parse(rates.Result);
            // Log.Information(rates_json.ToString());

            foreach (var tradingpair in rates_json)
            {
                Log.Information(tradingpair.Key);
                PoloniexTradingPair pair = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PoloniexTradingPair>(tradingpair.Value.ToString());
                Log.Information("logging pair");
                Log.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pair).ToString());
                context.Add(pair);

                Log.Information(pair.highestBid.ToString());

            }

            context.SaveChanges();



            /*
                JObject rates_json2 = JObject.Parse(rates_json.First.First.Last.First.ToString());
                string rates_json3 = rates_json.First.First.First.Last.ToString();
                CB_ExchangeRates ExchangeRates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CB_ExchangeRates>(rates_json.First.First.Last.First.ToString());
                ExchangeRates.currency = rates_json3;

                context.Add(ExchangeRates);
                context.SaveChanges();
                Log.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ExchangeRates));
                Log.Information("success!");
            */


            /*
            Log.Information("Pulling coinbase for exchange rates...");
            var json = httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-EUR/buy");

            JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(json.Result);


            CB_BTCEUR btceur = new CB_BTCEUR { Basecurrency = (string)jobject["data"]["base"], Targetcurrency = (string)jobject["data"]["currency"], Amount = (string)jobject["data"]["amount"] };
            */


        }
    }
}
```

During runtime, pair looks as expected:

```
    Id  7   int
    PoloniexTradingPairId   0   int
    baseVolume  0.70627038  decimal
    high24hr    0.00000005  decimal
    highestBid  0.00000004  decimal
    isFrozen    0   int
    last    0.00000004  decimal
    low24hr 0.00000004  decimal
    lowestAsk   0.00000005  decimal
    percentChange   0.00000000  decimal
    quoteVolume 17019678.54214583   decimal
```

I have no Idea how to find out which value actually causes the issue and cannot find any information within the exception except for: "Line Number 3". I assume it refers to the SQL query, is there any way to view the query?
The database seems to reflect my model, but something is still wrong.

Thanks for any hints to solving this issue! :)